# VBA use public variable when private variable has the same name

Tags: vba

Is it possible to have a 'public' variable and 'dim' variable with the same name and use both in the same sub?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The more local variable wins (*shadowing*).

To access the variable in the global scope you would need to qualify it with its containing module name:

```
Public Foo As Long

Sub g()
 dim Foo As String
 ...
 msgbox Foo
 msgbox ModuleName.Foo
```

Comment: Can't accept the answer for 5 more minutes but as soon as I can you got it, the hierarchy is Public, Private, Dim for scope am I missing anything else?

Comment: There is also `Static` and `Friend` although the latter is for class methods only

Comment: There is also Global that I think is even above Public.

Comment: Is there an MSDN documentation page on Scope, it seems strange that they have documentation for all the functions but not the basics of the language itself.

Comment: For office 2013 the language reference is in the [Office 2013 shared section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh872753(v=office.15).aspx)